# How are we able to use props when using React Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I was following a video tutorial about Redux from this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=93p3LxR9xfM). I went through the following article but I am unable to understand how can we use `this.props`. For example, consider this snippet of code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import axios from 'axios';
import { fetchPosts } from '../actions/postActions.js';

class Posts extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchPosts();
  }
  render() {
    const postItems = this.props.posts.map(el => {
      return (
        <div key={el.id}>
        <h3>{el.title} </h3>
        <p>{el.body} </p>
        </div>
      )
    })
    return (
      <div>
      <h1> Posts </h1>
      {postItems}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  posts: state.posts.items
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPosts } )(Posts);
```

Here we are using `this.props` in two places. First:

```
this.props.fetchPosts();
```

I'm not sure, but I believe this is calling our `fetchPosts` function from:

```
import { fetchPosts } from '../actions/postActions.js';
```

and then we also use it here:

```
this.props.posts.map(…)
```

This is the [current working repository](https://github.com/irohitb/redux-example) in case anyone wants to refer to the code. Since props flow from parent to child in one direction, can someone please explain how/why we are using `this.props` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux itself is not restricted to just React, it's just a general global store management library that encourages a single source of truth, and the use of actions and immutability for more stable and predictable apps.

The tutorial is using the `react-redux` package, which is an integration of Redux for React, providing components such as `Provider` and HOCs such as `connect`. The `Provider` component gives the capability of *providing* the Redux store to any of its children, and to receive the store in a child, you *connect* the child to the provider.

In this pattern, you use the `connect` function, which takes (usually) two arguments `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`, and returns another function which takes in a component, to provide the store to *via props*.

That's the key – `connect` connects a component to the store by passing down the parts of the Redux store you want (specified in `mapStateToProps`) to a component's props, mapping the global state to props, hence the name. The same goes for dispatch and action creators. This way, we can easily provide React components the ability to access the store and dispatch actions to change the global Redux store.

Concretely, in your example, the following line is used:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPosts })(Posts);
```

This connects the component `Post` to the global store. It also passes in two arguments to `connect`, the defined function `mapStateToProps`, and an object that specifies which action creators (containing `fetchPosts`) it wants to expose to `Post`. These are all passed as props to `Post`.

In `mapStateToProps`, the global state is passed into it. It returns an object specifying which parts of the global state you want to map as props to `Post`. That's why you're able to use `this.props.posts` – which is just a reference to `posts.items` in the global Redux store. We can also use `this.props.fetchPosts` because it's passed to `Post` by the second argument of `connect`.

I highly recommend reading through the [Redux documentation on integration with React](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react) and just all of it general. It gives examples and lots of guidance on good practice in Redux and its key concepts. Also, see [the API documentation for `react-redux`](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#api) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

`this.props.posts` and `this.props.fetchPosts` are from `connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPosts })`.

This is a React higher-order component. See:

https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options

Comment: Your english is just fine and thanks for the answer. 

The other answer was in very depth about the same.

Answer (score 1):

In [Redux](https://redux.js.org/), [`store`](https://redux.js.org/api-reference/store) is essentially an object that holds your application's top-level [`state`](https://redux.js.org/glossary#state).

Said `state` is updated using [`actions`](https://redux.js.org/api-reference/store#dispatch-action) and propagated throughout your application using a [`Provider`](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#provider-store).

The [`connect()`](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) method of [React Redux](https://redux.js.org/api-reference/store#dispatch-action) leverages [higher-order components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) to selectively transmit data to children by way of [`props`](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).

The overall process is very similar to [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), except that it enables developers to avoid a lot of the overhead that comes with alternative techniques such as prop drilling or using [`context`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Comment: Nah mate. Your answer is fine  @Li357

Comment: I guess someone didn't like it. Thanks for the reply!